# RDP-client with customizability

Tags: usb, rdp, rdesktop

I need to connect from a Thin Client to a Windows server 2003, for a remote desktop session.

The thin client will run Ubuntu 14, but I'll need a RDP-client that supports USB-passthrough, smart-card, local printing, keyboard type passthrough and automatic RDP-server detection.

Would it be easier to develop it, or use rdesktop with some plugins?

I'm a little bit lost, so any help would be greatly appreciated.